# Conscrypt with jdk8 to enable ALPN for http2

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, http2, alpn, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have been searching how to implement **Conscrypt** SSL provider using **conscrypt-openjdk-uber-1.4.1.jar** for jdk8 to support **ALPN** for making a **http2(using apache httpclient 5)** connection to a server as **jdk8 does not support ALPN by default** or the other solution is to migrate to jdk9(or higher) which is not feasible for now as our product is **heavily dependent on jdk8**

I have been searching extensively for some docs or examples to implement but I could not find one.

I have tried to insert conscrypt provider as default and my program takes it as default provider but still it fails to connect with http2 server, my example is as follows,

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.insertProviderAt(new OpenSSLProvider(), 1);
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new TrustAllStrategy()).build();
    final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create().setTlsStrategy(new H2TlsStrategy(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)).build();
    final IOReactorConfig ioReactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5)).build();
    final MinimalHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createMinimal(HttpVersionPolicy.FORCE_HTTP_2, H2Config.DEFAULT, null, ioReactorConfig, connectionManager);

    client.start();
    final HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 8082, "https");
    final Future<AsyncClientEndpoint> leaseFuture = client.lease(target, null);
    final AsyncClientEndpoint endpoint = leaseFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        String[] requestUris = new String[] {"/"};
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(requestUris.length);
        for (final String requestUri: requestUris) {
            SimpleHttpRequest request = SimpleHttpRequest.get(target, requestUri);
            endpoint.execute(SimpleRequestProducer.create(request), SimpleResponseConsumer.create(), new FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void completed(final SimpleHttpResponse response) {
                            latch.countDown();
                            System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + response.getCode());
                            System.out.println(response.getBody());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                            latch.countDown();
                            System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + ex);
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void cancelled() {
                            latch.countDown();
                            System.out.println(requestUri + " cancelled");
                        }

                    });
        }
        latch.await();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        endpoint.releaseAndReuse();
    }

    client.shutdown(ShutdownType.GRACEFUL);
}
```

this programs gives the output as

> org.apache.hc.core5.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
>   org.apache.hc.core5.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.FrameInputBuffer.read(FrameInputBuffer.java:146)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractHttp2StreamMultiplexer.onInput(AbstractHttp2StreamMultiplexer.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.AbstractHttp2IOEventHandler.inputReady(AbstractHttp2IOEventHandler.java:63)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.http2.impl.nio.ClientHttp2IOEventHandler.inputReady(ClientHttp2IOEventHandler.java:38)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.onIOEvent(InternalDataChannel.java:117)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalChannel.handleIOEvent(InternalChannel.java:50)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processEvents(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:173)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doExecute(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:123)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:80)
>       at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

If I print the provider and version it prints as **Conscrypt version 1.0** and **JDK 1.8.0_162**, but still it fails to connect with a http2 endpoint

same chunk of code works perfectly if I connect using jdk9 with default provider, what I m missing here in conscrypt configuration?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know of Jetty working with Java 8 and [Conscrypt](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-ssl.html#conscrypt). Jetty includes a [client side library](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/http-client.html). Here is an [example](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-alpn/jetty-alpn-conscrypt-client/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/java/client/ConscryptHTTP2Client.java) connecting via HTTP/2 to a server. Maybe this could be an alternative for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my requirement is for apache httpclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replacing the default JSSE provider with Conscrypt is not enough. One also needs a custom `TlsStrategy` that can take advantage of Conscrypt APIs.

This what works for me with Java 1.8 and Conscrypt 1.4.1

```
static class ConscriptClientTlsStrategy implements TlsStrategy {

    private final SSLContext sslContext;

    public ConscriptClientTlsStrategy(final SSLContext sslContext) {
        this.sslContext = Args.notNull(sslContext, "SSL context");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean upgrade(
            final TransportSecurityLayer tlsSession,
            final HttpHost host,
            final SocketAddress localAddress,
            final SocketAddress remoteAddress,
            final Object attachment) {
        final String scheme = host != null ? host.getSchemeName() : null;
        if (URIScheme.HTTPS.same(scheme)) {
            tlsSession.startTls(
                    sslContext,
                    host,
                    SSLBufferMode.STATIC,
                    (endpoint, sslEngine) -> {
                        final SSLParameters sslParameters = sslEngine.getSSLParameters();
                        sslParameters.setProtocols(H2TlsSupport.excludeBlacklistedProtocols(sslParameters.getProtocols()));
                        sslParameters.setCipherSuites(H2TlsSupport.excludeBlacklistedCiphers(sslParameters.getCipherSuites()));
                        H2TlsSupport.setEnableRetransmissions(sslParameters, false);
                        final HttpVersionPolicy versionPolicy = attachment instanceof HttpVersionPolicy ?
                                (HttpVersionPolicy) attachment : HttpVersionPolicy.NEGOTIATE;
                        final String[] appProtocols;
                        switch (versionPolicy) {
                            case FORCE_HTTP_1:
                                appProtocols = new String[] { ApplicationProtocols.HTTP_1_1.id };
                                break;
                            case FORCE_HTTP_2:
                                appProtocols = new String[] { ApplicationProtocols.HTTP_2.id };
                                break;
                            default:
                                appProtocols = new String[] { ApplicationProtocols.HTTP_2.id, ApplicationProtocols.HTTP_1_1.id };
                        }
                        if (Conscrypt.isConscrypt(sslEngine)) {
                            sslEngine.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
                            Conscrypt.setApplicationProtocols(sslEngine, appProtocols);
                        } else {
                            H2TlsSupport.setApplicationProtocols(sslParameters, appProtocols);
                            sslEngine.setSSLParameters(sslParameters);
                        }
                    },
                    (endpoint, sslEngine) -> {
                        if (Conscrypt.isConscrypt(sslEngine)) {
                            return new TlsDetails(sslEngine.getSession(), Conscrypt.getApplicationProtocol(sslEngine));
                        }
                        return null;
                    });
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .setProvider(Conscrypt.newProvider())
            .build();
    final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
            .setTlsStrategy(new ConscriptClientTlsStrategy(sslContext))
            .build();
    try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setVersionPolicy(HttpVersionPolicy.NEGOTIATE)
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build()) {

        client.start();

        final HttpHost target = new HttpHost("nghttp2.org", 443, "https");
        final String requestUri = "/httpbin";
        final HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();

        final SimpleHttpRequest request = SimpleHttpRequests.GET.create(target, requestUri);
        final Future<SimpleHttpResponse> future = client.execute(
                SimpleRequestProducer.create(request),
                SimpleResponseConsumer.create(),
                clientContext,
                new FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void completed(final SimpleHttpResponse response) {
                        System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + response.getCode() + " " +
                                clientContext.getProtocolVersion());
                        System.out.println(response.getBody());
                        final SSLSession sslSession = clientContext.getSSLSession();
                        if (sslSession != null) {
                            System.out.println("SSL protocol " + sslSession.getProtocol());
                            System.out.println("SSL cipher suite " + sslSession.getCipherSuite());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(requestUri + "->" + ex);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void cancelled() {
                        System.out.println(requestUri + " cancelled");
                    }

                });
        future.get();

        System.out.println("Shutting down");
        client.shutdown(CloseMode.GRACEFUL);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works with few modifications, thanks for your efforts @oleg

Comment: @Zyber You might want to share your modifications here or with Apache HttpComponents

Comment: the changes are mostly like typos thats why I didn't share, anyway I ll share so that it may help people like me

**1**. tlsSession.startTls is only accepting 4 parameters(sslcontext, SSLBufferManagement, SSLSessionInitializer, SSLSessionVerifier) it doesnt accept **host** as a parameter
**2**.second parameter in above method only accepts as SSLBufferManagement not as SSLBufferMode like in the code snippet
**3**.SimpleHttpRequests.GET.create(target, requestUri) can be replaced by SimpleHttpRequest.get(target, requestUri)
**4**.CloseMode.GRACEFUL can be replace by ShutDownType.GRACEFUL

Comment: And your snippet used CloseableHttpClient, I have changed it to MinimalHttpAsyncClient for multiplexing in http2

Comment: You are still using 5.0 BETA1. I would recommend upgrading to 5.0 BETA2

Comment: this works good but the **connection is closed** from httpclient after few exchanges(verified from wireshark as my client sends (RST, ACK)). I have set **keepAliveTime and maxKeepAliveRequests as "-1"** on server side so It indefinitely waits without closing. 

How to keep the connection open indefinitely from httpclient?

Thanks In Advance